# Removing Duplicates through VBA still throws pop up despite displayalerts=false

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

Column C in my spreadsheet contains values that will be client-chosen and frequently updated. I want column D to have data validation applied dynamically that pulls from that list. However, it needs to contain alphabetically ordered, unique values.

What I am currently doing is using the following formula to alphabetically order those values in a hidden column (BK). (Note: the site I found this on indicated it should only show unique values, however it did not).

```
{=INDEX(List,MATCH(0,IF(MAX(NOT(COUNTIF($BK$15:BK15,List))*(COUNTIF(List,">"&List)+1))=(COUNTIF(List,">"&List)+1),0,1),0))}
```

To update column D dynamically, I am using the following code:

```
Dim NewRng As Range
Dim RefList As Range, c As Range, rngHeaders As Range, RefList2 As Range, msg

On Error GoTo ErrHandling


Set NewRng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("D16:D601"), Target)
If Not NewRng Is Nothing Then

    Set rngHeaders = Range("A15:ZZ16").Find("Status List", After:=Range("E15"))
    Set RefList = Range(rngHeaders.Offset(1, 0).Address, rngHeaders.Offset(100, 0).Address)
    RefList.Copy
    RefList.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Set RefList2 = RefList.Offset(0, 1)


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    RefList2.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1


    For Each c In NewRng
        c.Validation.Delete
        c.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                                 AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                 Formula1:="=" & RefList2.Address

    Next c
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

This seems to work, except every time I click in a cell in column D it still throws a pop up box called "Remove Duplicates" that shows two checked checkboxes -- "Select All" and "Column BL". It also tells me how many duplicates were found and how many unique values will remain.

I am at a loss for why displayalerts=false hasn't turned this off, but it definitely isn't an option to have this fire every time someone clicks in column D. Has anyone seen this before? (I am on Excel for Mac 2016 by the way).

Comment: you can try Record Macro to compare the generated code. `RefList2.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-removeduplicates-method-excel

Comment: I added Header:=xlNo this morning, but I'm still getting the pop-up it seems.

Comment: I thought the issue might be that you are not passing array to Columns

Comment: I don't think it is, I've tried it both ways :/

Comment: then my other guess is if there is any protection on the sheet. I just noticed the Excel 2016 for Mac part, so might be worth trying it on windows just in case.

Comment: No protection on the sheet currently either, and I don't have access to a Windows machine. As a separate issue, when trying to record a macro, nothing seems to actually record. I choose to call the macro Macro4, start recording, take some actions, stop recording, and all I have in my new macro is: Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
End Sub

Comment: Might be limited to the Mac version.  For what it's worth, with Excel 2010 on Windows, a call to `RemoveDuplicates` does not give the alert by default when called from VBA.  I'm not sure if I have any ability to make the alert show up.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was afraid of. I haven't seen any reference to this issue elsewhere on Mac boards, but I've tried on a few different Mac computers here. My office uses all Macbooks though, so we're going to need to find a way to make this work. Perhaps using an Instr() formula to detect duplicates before pasting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around using RemoveDuplicates to achieve the desired result. Credit to Jean-Francois Corbett and SJR for some of the code that builds this solution. See below:

```
Public varUnique As Variant

Public ResultingStatus As Range
Public WhenAction As Range
Public EvalForm As Range



'Remove Case Sensitivity
  Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Prevents users from deleting columns that would mess up the header box
If Selection.Rows.Count = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:H")) Is Nothing Then

        Range("A1").Select
    End If

End If


Call StatusBars(Target)

Dim rngIn As Range
Dim varIn As Variant
Dim iInCol As Long
Dim iInRow As Long
Dim iUnique As Long
Dim nUnique As Long
Dim isUnique As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim ActionRng As Range
Dim EvalRng As Range
Dim ActionList As Range, c As Range, rngHeaders As Range, ActionList2 As Range, msg
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set ResultingStatus = Range("A15:Z15").Find("Resulting Status")
Set WhenAction = Range("A15:Z15").Find("When can this action")
Set EvalForm = Range("A15:Z15").Find("Evaluation Form")


'When can action be taken list

    'On Error GoTo ErrHandling



Set ActionRng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("D16:D601"), Target)
    If Not ActionRng Is Nothing Then
        Set rngIn = Range(ResultingStatus.Offset(1, 0).Address, ResultingStatus.Offset(1000, 0).End(xlUp).Address)
        varIn = rngIn.Value

        ReDim varUnique(1 To UBound(varIn))

        nUnique = 0
        For i = LBound(varIn) To UBound(varIn)
            isUnique = True
            For iUnique = 1 To nUnique
                If varIn(i, 1) = varUnique(iUnique) Then
                    isUnique = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next iUnique
            If isUnique = True Then
                nUnique = nUnique + 1
                varUnique(nUnique) = varIn(i, 1)
            End If
        Next i

        '// varUnique now contains only the unique values.
        '// Trim off the empty elements:
        ReDim Preserve varUnique(1 To nUnique)

        QuickSort varUnique, LBound(varUnique), UBound(varUnique)


        myvalidationStr = ""
        For Each x In varUnique
            myvalidationStr = myvalidationStr & x & ","
        Next x

        myvalidationStr = Left(myvalidationStr, Len(myvalidationStr) - 1)

            With ActionRng.Validation

                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:=myvalidationStr
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With

    End If


Here:
'Eval forms

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Evaluation Forms")
Dim EvalList As Range, EvalList2 As Range, EvalHeader As Range

On Error GoTo ErrHandling2
Set EvalRng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("E16:E601"), Target)
Dim cUnique As Collection
Dim vNum As Variant
Set cUnique = New Collection

If Not EvalRng Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In ws.Range("A15:A105")
            If c.MergeCells Then
                cUnique.Add c.Value, CStr(c.Value)
            End If
    Next c

QuickSort2 cUnique, 1, cUnique.Count


        myvalidationStr = ""
        For Each x In cUnique
            myvalidationStr = myvalidationStr & x & ","
        Next x

        myvalidationStr = Left(myvalidationStr, Len(myvalidationStr) - 1)

            With EvalRng.Validation

                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:=myvalidationStr
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With

    End If





Here2:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub

ErrHandling:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & _
            Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        Debug.Print msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    Resume Here

ErrHandling2:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & _
            Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        Debug.Print msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    Resume Here2


End Sub



'Sort array
Sub QuickSort(varUnique As Variant, first As Long, last As Long)

  Dim vCentreVal As Variant, vTemp As Variant

  Dim lTempLow As Long
  Dim lTempHi As Long
  lTempLow = first
  lTempHi = last

  vCentreVal = varUnique((first + last) \ 2)
  Do While lTempLow <= lTempHi

    Do While varUnique(lTempLow) < vCentreVal And lTempLow < last
      lTempLow = lTempLow + 1
    Loop

    Do While vCentreVal < varUnique(lTempHi) And lTempHi > first
      lTempHi = lTempHi - 1
    Loop

    If lTempLow <= lTempHi Then

        ' Swap values
        vTemp = varUnique(lTempLow)

        varUnique(lTempLow) = varUnique(lTempHi)
        varUnique(lTempHi) = vTemp

        ' Move to next positions
        lTempLow = lTempLow + 1
        lTempHi = lTempHi - 1

    End If

  Loop

  If first < lTempHi Then QuickSort varUnique, first, lTempHi
  If lTempLow < last Then QuickSort varUnique, lTempLow, last

End Sub

'sort collections
Sub QuickSort2(cUnique As Collection, first As Long, last As Long)

  Dim vCentreVal As Variant, vTemp As Variant

  Dim lTempLow As Long
  Dim lTempHi As Long
  lTempLow = first
  lTempHi = last

  vCentreVal = cUnique((first + last) \ 2)
  Do While lTempLow <= lTempHi

    Do While cUnique(lTempLow) < vCentreVal And lTempLow < last
      lTempLow = lTempLow + 1
    Loop

    Do While vCentreVal < cUnique(lTempHi) And lTempHi > first
      lTempHi = lTempHi - 1
    Loop

    If lTempLow <= lTempHi Then

      ' Swap values
      vTemp = cUnique(lTempLow)

      cUnique.Add cUnique(lTempHi), After:=lTempLow
      cUnique.Remove lTempLow

      cUnique.Add vTemp, Before:=lTempHi
      cUnique.Remove lTempHi + 1

      ' Move to next positions
      lTempLow = lTempLow + 1
      lTempHi = lTempHi - 1

    End If

  Loop

  If first < lTempHi Then QuickSort cUnique, first, lTempHi
  If lTempLow < last Then QuickSort cUnique, lTempLow, last

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found a way to suppress or auto-accept the pop-up box, which is causing further problems because it means the cell in column D that I select is no longer selected, so I can't choose from the drop-down list. **However, I'm wondering if anyone has any alternate ideas that might be simpler than my approach above.**

Essentially I have two different scenarios that I need to achieve:

- The above scenario, in which I need to pull only unique values from
  column C into a data validation drop down in column D.
- I also need to create drop-down lists based on values on another page that **are not** currently in list format. For example, in the code below I am looking for any value that is currently in a header on another page (i.e. the cells are merged). Right now I am Find/Copy/Paste/Validating but this seems complicated. And of course it suffers from the same pop-up issue as scenario 1.

  ```
  Dim EvalRng As Range
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Evaluation Forms")
  Dim EvalList As Range, EvalList2 As Range, EvalHeader As Range

  On Error GoTo ErrHandling2

  Set EvalRng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("E16:E601"), Target)
  Set EvalHeader = Range("A15:ZZ16").Find("Evaluation Forms List", 
  After:=Range("E15"))

  If Not EvalRng Is Nothing Then

  For Each c In ws.Range("A15:A105")
      If c.MergeCells Then
          c.Copy
          EvalHeader.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
          Set EvalHeader = EvalHeader.Offset(1, 0)
      End If


  Next c

  'Set EvalList = Range(EvalHeaders.Offset(1, 0).Address, EvalHeaders.Offset(100, 0).Address)
  Set EvalList = EvalHeader.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)

  EvalList.Copy
  EvalList.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Set EvalList2 = EvalList.Offset(0, 1)


  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  EvalList2.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), header:=xlNo


  For Each c In ActionRng
      c.Validation.Delete
      c.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                               AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                               Formula1:="=" & EvalList2.Address

  Next c
  ```

  End If

Comment: You should probably edit your original question instead of posting this follow-up as an answer.  Regardless, you might find you can make this process simpler if you can aggregate all of these different lists onto a single, possibly new, sheet.  On that sheet, you are free to use as many helper columns as you want which should make it much simpler to figure out how to sort, filter unique, and create a single list to use for the data validation.  Trying all of those in a single array formula is a recipe for pain and all of these downstream issues with VBA may just go away with another approach.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing the difference. I'm not currently using an array, I"m copying data to a list in the same sheet. I could add them to a different sheet instead but it seems like the "Remove Duplicates" issue will remain whether it's on the current sheet or a different one. I think what I was getting at is for those values for which I am using .Find on other sheets to pull in, it would be better if I could add them to a variable of some kind (array?), which would then be the Formula1 of the data val, rather than pasting them into a list first.

Comment: I was trying to indicate that you should find a way to not use `RemoveDuplicates` since it seems to be causing the trouble.  You mentioned above trying to use a formula to only return unique items; that technique should work.  The formula above may not work, but there is a formula that can do that.  If you cannot find a single formula, string a couple together on a helper sheet.  Alternatively, you can push the items into a `Dictionary` on the VBA side which prevents duplicates and then output from there.